# When parsing a json response object from an api call in python, is there a way to evaluate links from response to get only embedded data?

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, data-science

I am trying to use the requests package of Python to make an API call to load data in json format. I intend to use the data for analysis, so I am hoping to take away only embedded data. When I run the python code below, I receive a json object like the one listed:

```
import requests
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(req.json())
```

This returns:

```
{
"count": 15,
"next": "https:<<url>>/hours/?page=2",
"previous": null
}
```

Is there a way to get the json object response of "https:<>/hours/?page=2" when I make the initial api call? The actual structure I'm working with contains thousands of these urls.

Comment: What do you mean by "assess the value"?

Comment: Sorry, by "assess the value", I meant get the json object response of that url

Comment: In order to get the response from a url, you'll have to actually call the url. If there are thousands, you may not want your code automatically calling all of them at once.